# C# Reflection help needed

Tags: c#, reflection

```
 public partial class BaseClass : Form
{
    private bool myBaseBool;
    private NewClass newClass = new NewClass();

    public BaseClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildClass childC = new ChildClass();
        newClass.NewClassInt = 50;
        childC.RunTest();
        bool testBool = myBaseBool;
    }

    private void DoSomething(int number, string text)
    {
        int i = number;
        string s = text;
    }
}

public class NewClass
{
    public int NewClassInt = 10;
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public void RunTest()
    {
        //Test one setting base class private testBool ------ Working
        var myObj = this;
        var myField1 = typeof(ChildClass).BaseType.GetField("myBaseBool", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        myField1.SetValue(myObj, true);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Test two invoking base class private method -------- Working
        object[] ob = {1, "test"};
        typeof(ChildClass).BaseType.GetMethod("DoSomething", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(myObj, ob);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //Test three get value from base class instance of NewClass -------- Not Working
        var myField2 = typeof(ChildClass).BaseType.GetField("newClass", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        var value = ((NewClass) myField2.GetValue(myObj)).NewClassInt;//Always gets the default value of NewClass
    }
}
```

}

Why is test three returning the default NewClassInt value and not returning the base class instance NewClassInt value?

Please no "why do you want to do that questions" I seen enough of them when it comes to the subject Reflection. All I'm doing is trying to learn.

Comment: You're running the tests on `childC` but changing the value of `NewClassInt` in the current instance of `BaseClass`. Those are two completely separate objects.

Comment: If they are separate objects how is it I can get and set `myBaseBool` field on `BaseClass` from `childC`  `newClass` is a field on the `BaseClass`. Is it because `newClass` is an instance of a class even though it's an initialized field on the `BaseClass`?

Comment: I done some more testing and found the answer to my last question. Class instance fields don't work like other fields the only way to get the code to work is if the class instance is marked `static` and the `BindingFlags.Static` is added to the code.